# Unity ML-Agents 3DBall example, where do I run the mlagents-learn command from?

Tags: unity

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ml-agents/blob/main/docs/Learning-Environment-Executable.md#using-an-environment-executable

It says, "Navigate to the folder where you installed the ML-Agents Toolkit. If you followed the default installation, then navigate to the ml-agents/ folder.
Run mlagents-learn  --env=<env_name> --run-id="

So I tried

```
(unityml) nobu@LAPTOP-DNCQ5AAC:/mnt/d/1_gatechSpring2023/gameAI/ml-agents/Project/Assets/ML-Agents/Examples$ mlagents-learn /mnt/d/1_gatechSpring2023/gameAI/ml-agents/config/ppo/3DBall.yaml --env=3DBall --run-id=firstrun

            ┐  ╖
        ╓╖╬│╡  ││╬╖╖
    ╓╖╬│││││┘  ╬│││││╬╖
 ╖╬│││││╬╜        ╙╬│││││╖╖                               ╗╗╗
 ╬╬╬╬╖││╦╖        ╖╬││╗╣╣╣╬      ╟╣╣╬    ╟╣╣╣             ╜╜╜  ╟╣╣
 ╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╖│╬╖╖╓╬╪│╓╣╣╣╣╣╣╣╬      ╟╣╣╬    ╟╣╣╣ ╒╣╣╖╗╣╣╣╗   ╣╣╣ ╣╣╣╣╣╣ ╟╣╣╖   ╣╣╣
 ╬╬╬╬┐  ╙╬╬╬╬│╓╣╣╣╝╜  ╫╣╣╣╬      ╟╣╣╬    ╟╣╣╣ ╟╣╣╣╙ ╙╣╣╣  ╣╣╣ ╙╟╣╣╜╙  ╫╣╣  ╟╣╣
 ╬╬╬╬┐     ╙╬╬╣╣      ╫╣╣╣╬      ╟╣╣╬    ╟╣╣╣ ╟╣╣╬   ╣╣╣  ╣╣╣  ╟╣╣     ╣╣╣┌╣╣╜
 ╬╬╬╜       ╬╬╣╣      ╙╝╣╣╬      ╙╣╣╣╗╖╓╗╣╣╣╜ ╟╣╣╬   ╣╣╣  ╣╣╣  ╟╣╣╦╓    ╣╣╣╣╣
 ╙   ╓╦╖    ╬╬╣╣   ╓╗╗╖            ╙╝╣╣╣╣╝╜   ╘╝╝╜   ╝╝╝  ╝╝╝   ╙╣╣╣    ╟╣╣╣
   ╩╬╬╬╬╬╬╦╦╬╬╣╣╗╣╣╣╣╣╣╣╝                                             ╫╣╣╣╣
      ╙╬╬╬╬╬╬╬╣╣╣╣╣╣╝╜
          ╙╬╬╬╣╣╣╜
             ╙

 Version information:
  ml-agents: 0.30.0,
  ml-agents-envs: 0.30.0,
  Communicator API: 1.5.0,
  PyTorch: 1.7.1+rocm3.8
[INFO] Learning was interrupted. Please wait while the graph is generated.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nobu/miniconda3/envs/unityml/bin/mlagents-learn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/nobu/miniconda3/envs/unityml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/learn.py", line 264, in main
    run_cli(parse_command_line())
  File "/home/nobu/miniconda3/envs/unityml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/learn.py", line 260, in run_cli
    run_training(run_seed, options, num_areas)
  File "/home/nobu/miniconda3/envs/unityml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/learn.py", line 136, in run_training
    tc.start_learning(env_manager)
  File "/home/nobu/miniconda3/envs/unityml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents_envs/timers.py", line 305, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nobu/miniconda3/envs/unityml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/trainer_controller.py", line 197, in start_learning
    raise ex
  File "/home/nobu/miniconda3/envs/unityml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/trainer_controller.py", line 172, in start_learning
    self._reset_env(env_manager)
  File "/home/nobu/miniconda3/envs/unityml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents_envs/timers.py", line 305, in wrapped
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/nobu/miniconda3/envs/unityml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/trainer_controller.py", line 105, in _reset_env
    env_manager.reset(config=new_config)
  File "/home/nobu/miniconda3/envs/unityml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/env_manager.py", line 68, in reset
    self.first_step_infos = self._reset_env(config)
  File "/home/nobu/miniconda3/envs/unityml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/subprocess_env_manager.py", line 446, in _reset_env
    ew.previous_step = EnvironmentStep(ew.recv().payload, ew.worker_id, {}, {})
  File "/home/nobu/miniconda3/envs/unityml/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mlagents/trainers/subprocess_env_manager.py", line 101, in recv
    raise env_exception
mlagents_envs.exception.UnityEnvironmentException: Couldn't launch the 3DBall environment. Provided filename does not match any environments.
```

I'm literally in the folder where 3DBall is.

Comment: Do you have Unity open as well?

Comment: yes, now I had a problem where I would press play in the Editor and the Editor freezes right away.